# SQL Query which returns records with data type date and value '01/01/2001'?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hello I am currently converting data for a client. I am importing "|" delimited text files in to SQL Server 2008 R2. The customer has used '01/01/0001' as a blank date; however when i import this value SQL Server see's this date as "01/01/2001".

My original work around was importing as char(10) and then altering after the import. This worked for some but I have discovered that it doesn't always work!!!! Frustrating....

I need to do a search of all data types date with a value of '01/01/2001'

Comment: What does "doesn't always work!!!!" mean? I know it's frustrating but if we don't understand the whole problem it's frustrating for us to try to help solve it, too.

Comment: Have you tried using date or datetime2 for importing the dates, which should accept `'01/01/0001'`? What field type were/are you using?

Comment: Well, I don't hink `01/01/0001` is a good strategy for a "blank date" no matter what data type you're using. We have enough "magic values" that we don't need to create more. Use `NULL` instead.

Comment: There can be columns with valid date value - `01/01/2001` and i think you don't want to update them to `NULL`

Comment: @rs. fair point, but how is anyone on earth going to be able to identify which ones are 01/01/2001 on purpose, and which were by accident?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, yes you are right, OP may import them into varchar field, which will import data as is '01/01/0001' and then update them to null and copy to final table.

Comment: @rs. yes but I get the sense they want to update all the bad data that already got imported incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just update all instances to `NULL` (which is much better than some magic `01/01/0001` value) then you can say:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
UPDATE ' 
  +   QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]))
  + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME([object_id]))
  + ' SET ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' = NULL
      WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' = ''20010101'';'
FROM sys.columns
WHERE system_type_id = 40; -- date

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Now, I suspect the cases where this didn't work are cases where the data type is NOT in fact `date` but rather `datetime` / `smalldatetime`. So you may want this instead:

```
WHERE system_type_id IN (40,42,43,58,61);
```

If you still want to use this hocus pocus you can change this line:

```
  + ' SET ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' = NULL
```

To this:

```
  + ' SET ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' = ''00010101''
```

But this won't work if the column is `datetime`/`smalldatetime`!

Note that you should always use `YYYYMMDD`. [This `MM/DD/YYYY` stuff is a bad habit and prone to misinterpretation up and down the stack](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries).